# Phonegap change orientation at html page level

Tags: android, cordova, user-interface, screen-orientation

I have a phonegap application I want to show some pages at portrait level and some pages at landscape level. Is it possible. by the way I have disabled the orientation change and kept it at portrait in Android menifest.
NOTE: It will be cool if I can disable orientation change at Page Level Too. Since I want only One page to be rotating and all other pages static.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write some native coding for this.

OrientationHelper Class which is provided by Phonegap contains an event page_OrientationChanged

You can check for the page there in that event.

For Example

```
void page_OrientationChange(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
  if(CordovaBrowser.Source.ToString().Contains("pagename"))
   {
      int i = 0;

            switch (e.Orientation)
            {
                case PageOrientation.Portrait: // intentional fall through
                case PageOrientation.PortraitUp:
                    i = 0;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.PortraitDown:
                    i = 180;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.Landscape: // intentional fall through
                case PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft:
                    i = -90;
                    break;
                case PageOrientation.LandscapeRight:
                    i = 90;
                    break;
            }
   }
}
```

This should work